# difflib.get_close_matches is not giving any output when I compared 2 columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning, string-matching, fuzzywuzzy

I have 2 pandas dataframes, one with clean city names(df2) and another with unclean city names(df1).

sample values:

df2.city_name: bangalore

df1.city_name: bongolor

I tried to use the below code to get the close match for the city name

> city_names=df2.city_name.to_list()
>
> for i in df1.city_name:
> difflib.get_close_matches(i,city_names)

This is running for a very long time (more than an hour, so I stopped it).

I had tried fuzzywuzzy process as well. PFB:

> list1=df1.city_name.to_list()
> list2=df2.city_name.to_list()
>
> mat1=[]
>
> for i in list1:
> mat1.append(process.extract(i, list2, limit=10))
>
> df1['match']=mat1

This was also taking a very long time so I killed it.

Is there an optimized way to compare the column values and get the closer state name?

Note: my df1.city_names are 3.3M and df2.city_names are 2.7k

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: a faster alternative to `fuzzywuzzy` is `rapidfuzz`